# SQLAlchemy - Unable to commit the same field value without changing it

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to update some legacy data by querying a table and then committing the original values. I am performing client-side encryption using [SymmetricEncryptionClientSide](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/SymmetricEncryptionClientSide#example-two---use-typedecorator), which works great for new data. However, I need to update legacy data that's not encrypted yet. The encryption works on the SQLAlchemy model, basically encrypting data on the way in and decrypting it on the way out.

So my plan was to manually run a query on a table and then assign the same values to the fields and re-committing the data. This only works if the value assigned changes. If it's the same value it does not commit.

Here's my code:

```
user = session.query.(User).first()
user.name = user.name
session.commit
```

In the example above the data does not get commited again otherwise it would be encrypted. However, if I were to change;

```
user.name = user.name
```

to

```
user.name = user.name + 'o'
```

the data does get committed and the encryption happens. Why is this happening and is there a way to ensure that a value gets re-committed if I only reassign the same value to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy keeps track of the committed state of the ORM object. When a `flush()` or `commit()` occurs, the object is not sent back to the database if there have been no net changes to the object.

```py
engine.echo = True
with Session(engine) as sess:
    user = sess.get(User, 1)
    """
    BEGIN (implicit)
    SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name AS user_name 
    FROM user 
    WHERE user.id = ?
    [generated in 0.00044s] (1,)
    """
    user.name = user.name
    print(user._sa_instance_state.committed_state)  # {'name': 'gord'}
    sess.commit()
    """
    -- (no DML emitted)
    COMMIT
    """
```

Nothing is written back to the database because all of the object's attributes are the same as their committed state.

However, we can tell SQLAlchemy to update that column in the database by calling [flag_modified()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.flag_modified):

```py
engine.echo = True
with Session(engine) as sess:
    user = sess.get(User, 1)
    """
    BEGIN (implicit)
    SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name AS user_name 
    FROM user 
    WHERE user.id = ?
    [generated in 0.00044s] (1,)
    """
    flag_modified(user, "name")
    sess.commit()
    """
    UPDATE user SET name=? WHERE user.id = ?
    [generated in 0.00033s] ('gord', 1)
    COMMIT
    """
```

However, for a one-time encryption of previous entries I would bypass ORM and just update the column directly:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    not_yet_encrypted = conn.execute(select(User.id, User.secret_stuff))
    for_update = [
        dict(id=row.id, secret_stuff=aes_encrypt(row.secret_stuff))
        for row in not_yet_encrypted
    ]
    conn.execute(
        text(
            f"UPDATE {User.__tablename__} SET secret_stuff = :secret_stuff WHERE id = :id"
        ),
        for_update,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord this works like a charm. However, is there a way to change the committed state on a whole row? I would have to update multiple fields in a row and having to explicit change the state for each field.

Comment: @GordThompson wouldn't `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.flag_modified(user, 'name')` be a "cleaner" way or does it do something else?

Comment: @python_user - Yes, that is a better solution. Thanks!